# LUIS service is not visible in Luis.ai

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I have a LUIS api app id and key defined in my current project when I try to find this service in LUIS.AI its not visible. But when I test using LUIS API 2.0 console swagger, i can see response as successful. But my question is, I want to train and build using LUIS.AI website. I want to see list of intents present in my luis service and improve it accordingly. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely visiting the wrong LUIS URL for your [authoring region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-regions#luis-authoring-regions). For example, if you author your apps in `westeurope`, you need to visit [**eu**.luis.ai](https://eu.luis.ai) and not [www.luis.ai](https://www.luis.ai)

Answer (score 0):

If that still doesn't work, try using another browser. For me, strangely the app eventually disappeared from Chrome, but when I tried in Edge, it appears.

[image]